# how to pick one value from json encoded data using jquery?

Tags: jquery, json

jquery code:

```
   function getWriterBookName(url, data) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: data, //'foo='+ bar+'&calibri='+ nolibri,
        success: function (msg) {
            console.log(msg);

            console.log(msg.Product.name);
        }
    });
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Edit product info
    var url = 'loadbookWriter';
    $(".startLoading").on("change", function () {
        var pid = $(this).val();
        alert(pid);
        var data = 'id=' + pid;// +'&calibri=' + 'nolibri';
        getWriterBookName(url, data);
    });
    // End edit product info

});
```

console.log(msg);   give the following console output:

```
{"Product":{"id":"3","category_id":"2","name":"C","writer":"Santo","created":"2015-09-17 19:30:11"}}
```

I want to pick up name and writer value. I try this:

```
console.log(msg.Product.name);
```

but it does not work. How can I do this?

Comment: Works fine **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/q0q0jso6/1/)**

Comment: In what way does it not work?

Comment: I edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you missed is `dataType`:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    dataType:'json', //<-----add this.
    data: data, //'foo='+ bar+'&calibri='+ nolibri,
    success: function (msg) {
        console.log(msg);

        console.log(msg.Product.name);
    }
});
```

---

So, when you miss `dataType:"json"` when your source is returning json, then it is treated as `jsonstring` not a valid json.

So, Either you use `dataType:"json"` or in your success callback use to parse it as a valid json with `JSON.parse()`:

```
success: function (data) {
    var msg = JSON.parse(data); // <-----parse it if you don't have datatype set.
    console.log(msg.Product.name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var msg= {"Product":{"id":"4","category_id":"1","name":"C","writer":"santo","created":"2015-09-17 19:32:01"}}

$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("Name :" +msg.Product.name +", <br/>Writer:"+msg.Product.writer);
});
```